# Rules for using 'define'

Tags: c

Why b is **1**?

```
#define P1(x) x+x
#define P2(x) 2*P1(x)
int a=P1(1)?1:0;
int b=P2(a)&a;
```

I were trying simply input 1, for me it seems to return b=0, is there any rules for **#define**? Don't they 'act' as function in c?

Comment: Looks like an [operator precedence](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/104/fall06/burt/precedenceTable.html) problem to me.

Comment: Assuming that you mean `P1` (upper-case `P`) in the `P2` macro, then that expands as `2*x+x` which due to operator precedence is equivalent to `(2*x)+x` which might not always be what you want. This is just *one* "gotcha" that can happen with macros.

Comment: As for your question, can you please *elaborate*? Did you not get the result you expected? What do you mean with the word "rules"? "Rule of thumb"? "Rules in the C specification"? Some other rules? Or maybe just general guidelines?

Comment: Check the macro chapter of your beginner-level C programming book. It will tell you that every macro must be surrounded with parenthesis at appropriate places and show you some examples where not doing so will cause bugs.

Comment: Macros are most definitely ***not*** functions, they are handled by different parts of the compiler, and historically used to be handled by a separate program before the compiler even ran. Macros are replaced *as-is*.

Comment: Also, *what is the actual result of `b`*? It can't be either `1` or `0` as you state .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define P1(x) x+x
#define P2(x) 2*P1(x)
int a=P1(1)?1:0;
int b=P2(a)&a;
```

after code substitution it will look like this:

```
int a=1+1?1:0;
int b=2*a+a&a;
```

Since `1+1` is not `false`, `a` will be `1`, so:

```
int b=2*1+1&1
```

for clearness, I will write it with parenthesis (see [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)):

```
int b=((2*1)+1)&1
```

which is equivalent to:

```
int b=3&1
```

which is equivalent to:

```
int b=0b0011 & 0b0001
```

which is equivalent to:

```
int b=0b0001
```

which means `b=1`

Answer (score 1):

Macros are mere text replacement. Expanding your code, you will get this:

```
int a=1+1?1:0;
int b=2*a+a&a;
```

Note the complete and utter lack of parenthesis, which is caused by the macros in turn lacking appropriate parenthesis.

`1+1` is a non-zero value so `a` will be 1.

`b` will therefore be `2*1+1&1`. Follow the operator precedence rules in C,  `*` has highest precedence in the expression, followed by `+`, followed by `&`, followed by `=` which has lowest precedence.

So the expression is equivalent to: `b = ( ( (2*1) + 1) & 1);`

`2*1 == 2`, `2+1==3`, `3 & 1 == 1`.